# Merging XpsDocument for printing

Tags: wpf, xpsdocument

I have an wpf application working on print function for merging multiple xps documents as single. when working it triggers error as "Cannot perform a read operation in write-only mode."

I have load data from memorystream

```
xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(pack, CompressionOption.SuperFast, inMemPackageName);
```

and the i have use merging reference

```
FixedDocumentSequence sourceSequence = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();



foreach (DocumentReference dr in sourceSequence.References)                                             
{

    DocumentReference newDocumentReference = new DocumentReference();
    newDocumentReference.Source = dr.Source;
    (newDocumentReference as IUriContext).BaseUri = (dr as IUriContext).BaseUri;
    FixedDocument fd = newDocumentReference.GetDocument(true);
    newDocumentReference.SetDocument(fd);                                                seqNew.References.Add(newDocumentReference);
}
```

and then i have used this code to print

```
XpsDocumentWriterwriter=PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);                  
DocumentPaginator paginator = seqNew.DocumentPaginator;
if (paginator.PageCount == MassPrintings.Count())
{
   writer.Write(seqNew);
}
```

Please Suggest me a solution

Comment: Can you provide the code that is giving you the error, please?

Comment: while using xpsdocument writer it triggers error       XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);

Comment: @Bob can you suggest any solution for this problem?...